# jQuery How to properly set an interval?

Tags: jquery, slider, setinterval, intervals

At the moment I have this, but it keeps returning "swapBKgnd is no defined" :

```
    var interval = self.setInterval("swapBKgnd()", 9000);

function swapBKgnd() {

    (direction === 'next') ? ++current : --current;

    if (current === 0) {
        current = imgsLenth;
        direction = 'next';
    } else if (current - 1 === imgsLenth) {
        current = 1;
        loc = 0;
    }


    transition(sliderUL, loc, direction);
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try to declare `var interval` after `function` :)

Comment: var interval = setInterval(swapBKgnd, 9000);

Comment: remove the quotes from `swapBKgnd()`.

Comment: @karthikr and '()' too otherwise it will call function instantly

Comment: @the-val hmm, not returning any error... But doesn't appear to work still.

Comment: @Kennyist `(direction === 'next') ? ++current : --current;` can you explatin what this first line does for you?

Comment: Is the function in global scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the quotes from `swapBKgnd()`.

Use can do:

```
var interval = self.setInterval(swapBKgnd, 9000);
```

You havent declared `direction`, `current` or `loc` - those would throw errors

Comment: "var interval = self.setInterval(swapBKgnd(), 9000);"  this is wrong and "var interval = self.setInterval("swapBKgnd", 9000);" is wrong too

Comment: I Haven't posted the whole script. The are defined earlier on.